# Python: return an ordered list containing the indexes

Tags: python, loops, indexing, iteration

Trying to understand why my code returns the first position of a repeating capital letter for subsequent instances of said capital:

Task:
Return an ordered list containing the indexes of capitals in a given string

My Code:

```
def capitals(word):
    cap = []
    for i in word:
        if i.isupper():
            cap.append(word.index(i))
    return cap
```

Output:

`[1, 6, 9, 12, 13, 9]` should equal `[1, 6, 9, 12, 13, 14]`

Comment: Because that's what `index` does. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I guess index 13 and 14 have the same letter?

Comment: `word.index` only returns the index of the first match. If there are more than 2 same characters in the word, it always returns the first one.

Comment: More information : string.index works 
Like find() but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

Answer (score 5):

This could **actually** be simplified by

```
capitals = lambda word: [i for i,val in enumerate(word) if val.isupper()]
```

...and then it works with adjacent equal letters too:

```
capitals("ThiSiSaTeSTT")
> [0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Why assign a lambda to a name instead of just writing a normal function definition?

Comment: Cause it looks cool... No for real... In production I would have written it inside of a regular function, but I thought everybody does that in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be simplified to:

```
def capitals(word):
    return sorted([
        index for index, letter in enumerate(word) if letter.isupper()
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

this is to explain why your approach does not work and how it could be fixed:
you can give a second argument to `index`: a hint from where to start (i am giving the current position as hint); otherwise the first occurrence will be returned:

```
def capitals(word):
    cap = []
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter.isupper():
            cap.append(word.index(letter, i))
    return cap
```

and a more compact and pythonic version:

```
def capitals(word):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter.isupper()]
```